# Can not save permanent login state?

Tags: android, authentication

This is the code where I check whether user already Login or not .

But whenever I ran this code I always get this error .

I tried to solve it but I cannot .

**Here is my error**

```
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:371)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832): at   ndroid.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at   com.example.totallyfinish.MainActivity.saveLoggedIn(MainActivity.java:98)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at         com.example.totallyfinish.Login$4.onClick(Login.java:295)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-09 18:19:43.640: E/AndroidRuntime(832):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help me finding it please .

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton Imagebtn_start;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector conDetector;
private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
Notification myNotification;
SharedPreferences prefsNagSetting;
private static final String NAG_PREFS = "socially_you_nag_prefs";
/* THE EDITOR */
Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    jsonen();
     Imagebtn_start = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_btnstart);
     conDetector = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
     Imagebtn_start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     Intent intentfromLogin = getIntent();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            isInternetPresent = conDetector.isConnectingToInternet();
            Boolean value=true;

             if (isInternetPresent){

                    if (isLoggedIn()){
                       Intent team= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Team.class);
                       startActivity(team);
                    }
                    else{

                    Intent goLogin=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
                    startActivity(goLogin);
                    }
             }
             else{
                 showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "No Internet Connection",
                            "You don't have internet connection.", false);
             }
        }
    });
}

private boolean isLoggedIn() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    //The false represents the default value, if the variable is not stored
    boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
    return isLoggedIn;
}

public  void  saveLoggedIn(boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", value);
    editor.commit();
}
public void jsonen()
{
    int status=2;
    JSONObject json=null;
    String response = null;
    String teamID=null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    //postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",edit_txt_EmailAddress.getText().toString()));//// define the parameter
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID","396797666"));

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
       .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
       .penaltyLog().build());

    try {
          response=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/football365/notification.php", postParameters);
         // json=new JSONObject(response);
        //  teamID=json.getString("teamID");
         // Log.i("Team ID",teamID+"");
        }
   catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONObject jsonobj = null;
    String alerttime=null;
    String beforematch=null;
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    String starttime=null;
try{

    jsonobj = new JSONObject (response);
    jArray=jsonobj.getJSONArray("notifications");

    Log.i("Current Time",jArray+"");
    Log.i("Current Time",getCurrentTime());
    String currentTime="2013-12-07 14:03";
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

        jsonobj=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        alerttime=jsonobj.getString("alert");
        starttime=jsonobj.getString("startTime");
        beforematch=jsonobj.getString("beforeMatchTime");

        if(alerttime.equals(currentTime)){

                Notification(starttime);
                Log.i("Wintal", "wint");
        }
    }


}
catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}



Log.i("RESULT", jsonobj+"");
Log.i("time", alerttime+"");
Log.i("before Match",beforematch+"");
}

public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status){
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();


}

public String getCurrentTime(){
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    return strDate;
}

public void alert()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

      calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 12);
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
      calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);

      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13);
      calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

      Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}



public void Notification(String s)
{
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Ready for Play time."; // ticker-text
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Play Time";
        CharSequence contentText = "Your match is at "+s;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,ScheldueNotification .class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        // and this

        mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.vibrate = new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This is the code where I save a boolean to Editor

```
                        try {
                            Log.i("noTeam Win tal","Log in hmar");

                            userName=jsonobj.getString("userName");
                            userID=jsonobj.getString("userID");

                            noteamSaving[0]=userName;
                            noteamSaving[1]=userID;

                            Log.i("USerNameNN", userName+"");
                            Log.i("UserIDNN",userID+"");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Intent noteamshi=new Intent(Login.this,NoTeam.class);
                        noteamshi.putExtra("NoTeamSaving", noteamSaving);
                        startActivity(noteamshi);
                        MainActivity m=new MainActivity();
                        m.saveLoggedIn(true);
```

Comment: Can you post your full `LogCat` error. It is incomplete.

Comment: Are you initializing some values at class level?

Comment: @ Abishek . I already  updated :) thanks for concern

Comment: @ Agarwal which value you want to say ?

Comment: can you mark line 98 of MainActivity

Comment: I mean variables which are using context.

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); this is line no 97 & 98

Comment: There's no @ Agarwal :)

Comment: try using getApplicationContext() instead of this.

Comment: can u post whole mainactivity code

Comment: wait a minute @ anand

Comment: I put Mainactivity... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
MainActivity m=new MainActivity();
```

This probably doesn't do what you think it does. Instantiating an activity like this bypasses the normal activity life cycle. The error is because the activity object doesn't know what the package name for the application is. Move isLoggedIn() and saveLoggedIn(boolean value) inside the activity that is foreground when you want to call them so that the "this" reference refers to a properly initiated context.

If you need to access those methods from several activities you could change the methods like this:

```
class LoginHelper {
     public static boolean isLoggedIn(Context context) {
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
         //The false represents the default value, if the variable is not stored
         boolean isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
         return isLoggedIn;
     }

     public  void  saveLoggedIn(Context context, boolean value) {
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
         Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
         editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", value);
         editor.commit();
    }
}
```

And pass a pointer to the current activity for the context perimeter.

```
                    try {
                        Log.i("noTeam Win tal","Log in hmar");

                        userName=jsonobj.getString("userName");
                        userID=jsonobj.getString("userID");

                        noteamSaving[0]=userName;
                        noteamSaving[1]=userID;

                        Log.i("USerNameNN", userName+"");
                        Log.i("UserIDNN",userID+"");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Intent noteamshi=new Intent(Login.this,NoTeam.class);
                    noteamshi.putExtra("NoTeamSaving", noteamSaving);
                    startActivity(noteamshi);

                    LoginHelper.saveLoggedIn(this, true);
```

This is assuming the above block comes from an activity that android launched rather than one you manually instantiated.

Comment: LoginHelper.saveLoggedIn(this,true) . In this line this is not working

Comment: Did you create the LoginHelper class that I posted and import it in the file were you called it? What is the error you're getting?